# I can't click on my navigation bar HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm building a website but I can't click on my website's navigation bar on the home page.

I've tried changing many things like increasing the z position and have googled the problem. Unfortunately nothing works.

```css
 *{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    }

    .content {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    nav {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 30px;
 z-index: 2;
    }

    nav ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    nav li {
 display: inline-block;
    }

    nav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 5px 30px;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: 20px;
    }

    nav li.active a {
 border: 1px solid white;
    }

    nav li a:hover {
 border: 1px solid white;
    }

    body {
 font-family: monospace;
    }

    .hero {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
    }

    h1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 90px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20%;
    }
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="container">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="services.html"> Services </a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="hero">
   <h1>Label</h1>
   <div class="button">
    <a href="services.html" class="button button-one"> Learn More</a>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hero">
  <h2>Name</h2>
  </div>

 </header>
```

The 'Learn More' button that also links to the service page works fine but I still can't click on the navigation bar, even the services page. The hover effect doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm commenting since it's another way, but not a proper answer. You can solve this changing "float: right;" with something like "padding-left: 70%"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two elements with `.hero` class have `position:absolute;` and overlap your `<nav>` element. You can check it by deleting these elements.